# TSQL Reference Table with redundant keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a stored procedure on SQL Server 2016. In my Database I have a table structure and need to add another table, which references to the same table as an existing one.

Thus, I have 2 times a 1:1 relation to the same table.

The occuring problem is, I reference the same keys from 2 different origin tables twice in the same target table.

**Target table:**

```
FK_Tables | Text
----------------
  1       | Table One Text Id: 1
  1       | Table Two Text Id: 1 // The error: Same FK_Tables 2 times
```

**Table One:**

```
ID | OtherField
---------
 1 | 42
```

**Table Two:**

```
ID | CoolField
---------
 1 | 22
```

Table One and Table Two are currently referencing to the table Reference Table.

Do you know how I can solve this problem, of the same ID twice?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a column for each table you're referencing, otherwise you wouldn't know where the ID is coming from if they were all inserted into the same field. Something like this:

```
/*
CREATE TEST TABLES
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbOne;

CREATE TABLE tbOne ( ID     INT     IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL      PRIMARY KEY
                   , TXT    VARCHAR(10) 
                   );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbTwo;

CREATE TABLE tbTwo ( ID     INT     IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL      PRIMARY KEY
                   , TXT    VARCHAR(10) 
                   );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Target;

CREATE TABLE Target ( ID     INT    IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL      PRIMARY KEY
                    , FKTB1  INT
                    , FKTB2  INT
                    , TXT   VARCHAR(100) 
                    );



-- 1st FK tbOne
ALTER TABLE Target ADD CONSTRAINT FK_One FOREIGN KEY (FKTB1) REFERENCES tbOne (ID);

--2nd FK tbTwo
ALTER TABLE Target ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Two FOREIGN KEY (FKTB2) REFERENCES tbTwo (ID);



-- Populate test tables
INSERT INTO tbOne (TXT)
SELECT TOP 100 LEFT(text, 10)
FROM SYS.messages

INSERT INTO tbTwo (TXT)
SELECT TOP 100 LEFT(text, 10)
FROM SYS.messages



INSERT INTO [Target] (FKTB1, FKTB2, TXT)
SELECT 1, 1, 'Test - constraint'


-- Check result set
SELECT *
FROM tbTwo

SELECT *
FROM tbOne


SELECT *
FROM [Target] T
    INNER JOIN tbOne TB1
        ON T.FKTB1 = TB1.ID
    INNER JOIN tbTwo TB2
        ON T.FKTB2 = TB2.ID
```